# Multidimensional array from mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have 2 database tables: `categories` and `sub_categories`. `sub_categories` table is linked to `categories` table by category id `cat_id`

In php I want to print the parent category and all the sub-categories belonging to it. Is it possible to do so by creating a multidimensional array from **1** mysql query?

Example result:

```
array
(
  "Category 1"=>array
  (
  "Sub-category",
  "Sub-category",
  "Sub-category"
  ),
  "Category 2"=>array
  (
  "Sub-category"
  ),
  "Category 3"=>array
  (
  "Sub-category",
  "Sub-category",
  "Sub-category"
  )
 );
```

My query returns just 1 sub category for each category:

```
SELECT `categories`.`cat_title`, `sub_categories`.`sub_cat_title` 
FROM (`categories`) 
LEFT JOIN `sub_categories` 
ON `sub_categories`.`cat_id` = `categories`.`cat_id` 
GROUP BY `categories`.`cat_title`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL wont return an array, it will only return rows, but you can easily create the array with php.. just do this

```
<?php
  $db = new mysqli('host','user','password','database');
  $query =  "SELECT c.cat_title, s.sub_cat_title
             FROM categories c
             LEFT JOIN sub_categories s USING (cat_id)
             ORDER BY cat_title";
  $result = $db->query($query);
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $cats[$row['cat_title']][] = $row['sub_cat_title'];
  }        

?>
```

Comment: sorry typed group by, meant order by, if you group by you will only get one row for each title - although you don't need that either, php is pretty cool with arrays, it automatically inserts the next index into your multidimensional array and creates a new 1st dimension if it doesnt exist

Answer (score 1):

Try using ORDER BY instead.

```
ORDER BY `categories`.`cat_title`, `sub_categories`.`sub_cat_title`
```